# how to upload image from device

Tags: codenameone, image-uploading

I'm trying to upload image with:

`Capture.capturePhoto(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth(), -1);`

This launches the file explorer with simulator, but on a real device, camera is launched instead of file explorer.

Comment: It opens a file chooser because that's convenient for the simulator but the method is meant to capture a photo. Not upload it. There is a gallery picker API as well as a file picker cn1lib